# Making a single page application with ajax and get a 404 error when the page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Basically, I'm coding a personal website and have made a single page application with ajax so content is added to the page between the header and footer when a page in the navigation bar is clicked. I had to manually code the push state and pop state in order to get the back and forward arrows working, which they do. However, the only issue left is that when I reload the page, I get an entry not found error.

I'm very new to web dev and javascript so some of my code is a little messy. I know the reload issue has to do with the added page URL not actually existing on the server.

Here are the relevant pieces of my code:

HTML:

```
<nav>
   <ul class='nav-bar'>
      <li class='nav-item'><a id='writing'>Writing</a></li>
      <li class='nav-item'><a id='editing'>Editing</a></li>
      <li class='nav-item'><a id='about'>About</a></li>
      <li class='nav-item'><a id='contact'>Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Javascript

```
//change page on nav click
    $('.nav-bar li a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var page = $(this).attr('id');
        var file = page + '.html';
        var origin = window.location.origin;
        //nav color change for current page
        removeActiveLinks();
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: origin,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(response) {
                $('#content').load(file);
            },

            error: function(error) {
                console.log('There was an error', error);
            }
        });
        window.history.pushState(file, null, '/' + page);
    });

    //nav for home page
    $('#home').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        removeActiveLinks();
        $('#content').load('home.html')

        window.history.pushState('index.html', null, '/');
    });

    //ensure page back functionality
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
        var prevState = event.state;
        $('#content').load(prevState);
        removeActiveLinks();

        var page_id = '#' + prevState.split('.')[0];
        $(page_id).parent().addClass('active');
    });
```

[Here's what the error looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Keq0P.png)

Comment: The 3rd argument of pushState is the url... And you do push `page` which does not have the `.html` extention (in `$('.nav-bar li a').on('click'`).

Comment: You probably don't have any routes set for each of those pages and clearly don't have a fall back. Most (all?) SPA servers will response with to the default page (index.html) upon any page request.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - that crossed my mind too, but the OP is attempting to create a SPA - hence doesn't want to call individual HTML pages from the browser?

Comment: `var origin = window.location.origin;` will request the incomplete url on refresh.

Comment: Additionally... The jQuery `.load()` method is a shorthand for `$.ajax()`... So its an ajax request in an ajax success callback... mmm

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette even if I delete that line and put the URL as something else, the refresh still results in an error...as to your other point, should I delete the $.ajax() entirely? Also, really appreciate the help :)

Comment: I think I'm finished editing for a "no route:" SPA solution with the back navigation kept. Have a try.

Comment: What happens when you click on "Writing" menu?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something simpler, using simple `load()` (shorthand for ajax) and a the `state` of the history directly.

Not tested, but should work fine.

```
// Initial page load
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#content").load("home.html");
})

// Change page on nav click
$(".nav-bar li a, #home").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var file = this.id + ".html";

  //nav color change for current page
  $(".active").removeClass("active");
  if(this.id != "home"){
    $("#"+this.id).parent().addClass("active");
  }

  $("#content").load(file);
  window.history.pushState(file, null, "/");
});

// Ensure page back functionality
window.addEventListener("popstate", function (event) {
  var prevState = event.state;
  $("#content").load(prevState);

  var page_id = "#" + prevState.split(".")[0];
  $(".active").removeClass("active");

  if(page_id != "#home"){
    $(page_id).parent().addClass("active");
  }
});
```

But there is no `/writing` in the adress bar with this solution. If you insist on it, you will have to dive in more complex route settings on the server.